# How to use the ExactIntersect flag for QgsFeatureRequest() object

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsfeaturerequest

I have two layers, a `polygon_lyr` and a `line_lyr`. I want to use a `QgsFeatureRequest()` for the `line_lyr.getFeatures()` but instead of returning the lines which intersect the bounding box of a polygon, I just want the lines which intersect the actual polygon geometry. I assume this is what `ExactIntersect` flag does. But I do not know how to actually use it.

```
for i, poly in enumerate(polygon_lyr.getFeatures()):
    poly_geom = poly.geometry()

    for line in line_lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(poly_geom.boundingBox())):
        #processing operations
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible as the [QgsFeatureRequest()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html) class must use a specified bounding box if you want to add a spatial filter. An example method is`QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(boundingBox)`. The `ExactIntersect` flag instead uses the actual geometry of the feature for intersection, but it will be used against the bounding box.

The following is an example of using `QgsFeatureRequest()` where the geometry of each line is intersected with the bounding box of each polygon:

```
polygon_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon example')[0]
line_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('line example')[0]
ids = []

for i, poly in enumerate(polygon_lyr.getFeatures()):
    poly_geom = poly.geometry()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(poly_geom.boundingBox()).setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.ExactIntersect)
    for line in line_lyr.getFeatures(request):
        ids.append(line.id())

line_lyr.selectByIds(ids)
```

---

If you want to do an intersection using the line geometries against the polygon geometries, you could do this more directly using:

```
polygon_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon example')[0]
line_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('line example')[0]
ids = []

for i, poly in enumerate(polygon_lyr.getFeatures()):
    poly_geom = poly.geometry()
    for line in line_lyr.getFeatures():
        if line.geometry().intersects(poly_geom):
            ids.append(line.id())

line_lyr.selectByIds(ids)
```